# Which tab is currently selected in Terminator?

Tags: gnome-terminal, terminator

In the terminal emulator **Terminator**, I find that it's hard to tell which tab I have selected at any given time.

Here's what the tabs look like in Terminator.

[image]

Here's what the tabs look like in Gnome terminal. Can I achieve such an obvious distinction in Terminator?

[image]

This makes a difference when I have many tabs open and want to move to a particular one with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>. I don't know which of these key combinations to press because I don't know which of the tabs I'm currently occupying.

I'm using *Ubuntu (Desktop) 18.04.4*

(If there's no solution out of the box, is there a plugin that will give me the appearance I want?)

Comment: @K7AAY : thanks for the guidance. I've made that update above, in the penultimate paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on GTK3
You'll find what you are asking for [here](http://blog.nabam.net/workstation/2017/09/15/terminator_tabs/)

You'll need to edit these for the active tab, in your file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

- for background : `.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab:checked`
- for font : `.terminator-terminal-window notebook tab:checked label`

I think you will need to restart gnome-shell to force it to reload GTK css
<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> ; then run `r`

(correct me if I'm wrong)

This also figures in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Terminator)

Comment: Thanks! I found that running `r` did not load the changes, though it did appear to reload my shell. After a complete reboot, the changes did load.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Terminator, this setting is built into the Preferences panel.

Simply right-click any terminal pane and select **Preferences**.

The **Global** tab has a **Terminal Titlebar** section where you can set the colors:

[image: Terminal Titlebar settings in Terminator Preferences]

I am runing Terminator 1.91 installed with `apt get` on Ubuntu 20.4 and 18.4 systems, and this works on both.

Comment: This answer is about titlebar which is something else. The question is about the active tab.